# Calling a function from main() with parameters that belong to another function

Tags: c

I'm trying to call a function to calculate the weekday from my main() function, however, it is telling me that 2 of 3 of the arguments have been undeclared. These two arguments are also the ones that are found in another function, and I've made sure that I have put return  on both of these functions, but it is still giving me the error. The last parameter works fine as the variable declaration for it is found within the main() function as well.

So far, i've tried to do something like this within my main function:

```
int main (int argv, char **argc) 
{
int day;
int month;
int year;

day = get_integer();
month = get_integer();
year = get_integer();

printf("Ordinal Day: %d\n", calculate_ordinal_day(day, month, year, 
leap_year(year)));
calculate_iso_week_day(ordinal_day, week_day, year);
calculate_weeks_in_year(year);
/* calculate_week(year); */
return 0;
}
```

But it gave me an error and I don't think this is the way to do it anyway.

The two functions that I want the parameters from are here:

```
int calculate_ordinal_day(int day, int month, int year, int isyearleap) {
int ordinal_day;

if (month == 1) {
    return day;
}
if (month == 2) {
    return day + 31;
}

ordinal_day = myFloor(30.6 * month - 91.4) + day;
if (isyearleap == 1) {
    return ordinal_day + 60;
}
return ordinal_day + 59;
}


int day_of_the_week(int year)
{
int week_day;
week_day = (1 + 5 * ((year - 1) % 4) + 4 * ((year - 1) % 100) + 6 * ((year - 
1) % 400) ) % 7;
if (week_day == 0) {
    week_day = 7;
}
printf("The day of the week is %d\n", week_day);
return week_day;
}
```

And the function that I am attempting to use this for is:

```
int calculate_iso_week_day(int ordinal_day, int week_day, int year)
{
int iso_day_of_the_week;
iso_day_of_the_week = (ordinal_day + day_of_the_week(year)) % 7;
printf("ISO Weekday: %d\n", iso_day_of_the_week);
return iso_day_of_the_week;
}
```

P.S - the code in this question may be very similar to other questions. This is not a duplicate as the question is about something completely different.

Comment: Where's your main function?

Comment: Please post the full code and the full error message. But it seems from a first look that a good C book for beginners should be the first thing you should read (missing types in function declarations).

Comment: I've added the main function.

Comment: Am I able to post a link to the code instead? It's quite long

Comment: `ordinal_day` and `weekday` are not declared in the scope of `main`. So it is normal you get an error. And please post the verbatim error message you get.

Comment: Please read about a [mcve]. You will need to minimize the example to the minimal that still exhibits the behaviour, and the example needs to be complete. And you must provide the error message, which you didn't do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
calculate_iso_week_day(ordinal_day, week_day, year);
```

Alright, let's look at where those parameters are. `ordinal_day` is defined in `calculate_ordinal_day`. It's not visible from `main`, that's why it's complaining. Did you perhaps intend to use the result of `calculate_ordinal_day` instead? If so change this:

```
printf("Ordinal Day: %d\n", calculate_ordinal_day(day, month, year, 
leap_year(year)));
calculate_iso_week_day(ordinal_day, week_day, year);
```

To this:

```
int ordinal_day = calculate_ordinal_day(day, month, year, leap_year(year));
printf("Ordinal Day: %d\n", ordinal_day);
calculate_iso_week_day(ordinal_day, week_day, year);
```

It's similar with `week_day`. `main` can't see it. I would recommend this in your `main`:

```
int week_day = day_of_the_week(year);
```

Somewhere between assigning `year` and calling `calculate_iso_week_day`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it managed to compile when I did this! The answer isn't quite what I want it to be, but I think i'll be able to handle it from here :)

Comment: No problem, glad it worked.

Comment: I managed to completely fix it, answer is now correct etc, once again thanks a lot!